# local variable 'data' referenced before assignment Python3

Tags: python-3.x

How could I refactor to avoid this error `local variable 'data' referenced before assignment` ?

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def dropTheZeros(columnName): 

    for idx, row in data.iterrows():
        value = row[columnName]
        if isinstance(value, float) == True:
            if val == 0:
                data = data.drop(index = idx)

dropTheZeros('Budget')
```

Comment: pass `data` as argument in the function

Comment: I don't want to do that. I want to modifiy the global variable ```data``` every iteration when ```val==0```

Comment: define `data` as `global` variable

Comment: ```global data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')```  - invalid syntax

Comment: @bibscy writing a function to modify something without passing it as an argument is very bad practice, I think you should use `apply` instead

Comment: `global data` goes inside the function

Comment: I miss SWIFT, ```self.data = ...```

Comment: Also, best not to drop indicies while iterating the original object

Comment: Python has self keyword, too. You don't seem to need classes here

Comment: Right, so, if I am not dropping the indices, what would be the correct approach here?